# MariaDB InnoDb & Columnstore

Tags: linux, mariadb, innodb, columnstore

I have a DB mariadb with innodb tables with one, two million records.
I checked online and saw that Columnstore is faster.

I created a Columnstore table in my DB and put all the contents of the Innodb tables in Columnstore.

After that i ran queries but in my case Innodb is faster.

Innodb is faster than 200, 300 milliseconds.

Is there any setting for the Columnstore?

Why is InnoDB faster than Columbstore?

CPU 10core, 24GB RAM. MariaDb 10.11, Columnstore 6.4 and OS Debian 12.

I would like to understand why i don't have these benefits?

I had already read the link. But i didn't find anything useful...

Thank you

a help, a guide, a how to

Comment: https://mariadb.com/docs/columnstore/

Comment: Instead of adding details in an answer, you should [edit] your question with the details.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the queries.  Please show us the "slow" queries.

Columnstore is faster sometimes:

- Table scans are needed.
- Multiple range scans in a single query.
- The dataset is bigger than can be cached in RAM.  (Columnstore compresses 10x)

InnoDB is faster for traditional SQL queries

- "Point queries" -- single row involved.  (Often <10ms for a query.)
- A single range is involved, and that column is indexed.

Please show us the main queries you have; we can discuss further.